# how use datetimepicker with getfile

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        string Date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMM");

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\tbank_file\out\", "*.txt"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file);
    }
```

i want to use Variable date1 use in loop foreach of getfile

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: I wish you could be more clear with your question. Where do u want to use `Date1`

Comment: do you want to use the `Date1` as search pattern in `GetFiles` ?

Comment: can you please end this guessing game and describe precisely **how** you "want to use Variable date1 use in loop foreach of getfile"

Comment: @MongZhu OP seems asleep!

Comment: @o_O I can understand that, it's way to early for me either ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string Date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("ddMM");

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\tbank_file\out\", "*.txt"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file+" "+ Date1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\tbank_file\out\", "*.txt"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file+" "+ dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"););
    }
```